Package memoize (python-based extraction) Error: Python module 'pdfrw' was not found
I’m looking forward to running the memoize package to reduce my compile time, but after several days of research, I’m clueless. This is my first Python rodeo, so I may be missing something that to others would be obvious. Initially thought it was a path mismatch, but now I’m not so sure.
Configuration (Mac running Python 3.13.1 on Sequoia 15.1.1, compiling w LuaLaTeX using TeXShop 5.47):

My memoize.cfg is:

\mmzset{
  extract=python,    % Use the Python-based extern extraction method.
  auto={circuitikz}{memoize},   % Working on electrical circuits
  prefix=memos/,    % Use one memo directory for all documents in a folder.
 }


Terminal command python -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))’ yields:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python313.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages


Terminal command pip show pdfrw2 yields:

Name: pdfrw2
Version: 0.5.0
Summary: PDF file reader/writer library
Home-page: https://github.com/sarnold/pdfrw
Author: Patrick Maupin
Author-email: pmaupin@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:


My MWE memoize.tex (from Sec 2.1 in Memoize v1.4.1 December 2, 2024 package documentation):

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}

\usepackage[recompile]{memoize}

\begin{document}

Memoize will automatically externalize\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(node)
        [align=center,ellipse,draw]
        {TikZ\\pictures};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{forest}
    [and Forest trees [and]
    [Forest trees[Forest][trees]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

Results in the following console error:
memoize-extract.py: Python module 'pdfrw' was not found.
Have you followed the instructions is section 1.1 of the manual?
 (./memoize.mmz.log

./memoize.mmz.log:1: Package memoize (python-based extraction) Error: Python module 'pdfrw' was not found.

Note 1: I used pip 24.3.1 to install/uninstall/reinstall the Python module ’pdfrw2’ (as well as ’pdfrw’) several times. No luck.
Note 2: The documentation states: … install Python and library pdfrw2 and then use extract=python. It says nothing about installing pdfrw [w/o the 2].
Note 3: [From 2. above] The sys.path includes the path:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages which [From 3. above] is identical to the location of pdfrw2:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages.
This makes me think it’s not a path mismatch.
Lastly, I have no idea why the console error states that the pdfrw module is missing, when the documentation clearly states that memoize requires the pdfrw2 module.
What am I missing?

are you actually using that .tex file as-is? I posted an answer, but I've deleted it as I'm not sure it's the problem, but you have to load memoize before either tikz or forest.

can you try compiling on the command line? pdfrw2 calls itself pdfrw as far as I can tell.

@cfr - Thank you for your answer. Yes, I used the .tex file as is, and with your suggested changes. (Thanks for the tip!) No luck. I’ll have to research compiling on the (Terminal?) command line. Interesting that your python3 is at /usr/lib/python3.12/, while mine is at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/. No idea if that is significant. I downloaded and installed Python from Python web site (https://www.python.org/).

the difference in paths is expected. you are using a mac, while I am not. /Library is an apple invention. but now I'm wondering if you have more than one Python and whether TeX Shop picks up the right one. certainly mac used to come with python. however, I don't know if that is still the case. to compile on the command line, use Terminal, yes. you obviously use that already. you just change to the directory containing your .tex file and type the compilation command e.g. lualatex mydocument or pdflatex myfile or whatever. (you don't need the .tex extension, but it doesn't hurt.)

I do remember there were some complications in installing a second python. (I needed a newer version than apple provided at the time.) you can try which -a python and see if the results include anything unexpected. I think the pdfrw thing is that either pdfrw or pdfrw2 both call themselves pdfrw. it's possible this might be a problem if it actually installs as pdfrw2 because, as far as I can tell, memoize only looks for pdfrw ....

but I doubt you needed to install python. I think you could probably just have installed the library. you could also try the perl extraction method, which is default and seems to be 'first choice' in the current documentation. (the description of the python option has been downgraded.) macs definitely come with perl.

@cfr - FWIIW, I experienced similar issues with Perl; in the same fashion, Perl could not find the Perl library PDF::API2 (nor its fork, PDF::Builder). If I can get Python to work, the fix will likely inform the Perl fix as well. BTW, how do I load the tikz and forest packages prior to compiling Python .tex file on the command line? Got Link? Thanks!

you don't. you just compile your tex file normally e.g. pdflatex myfile.tex or whatever. are you using the os's perl? which library did you install? for perl you may need to export an environment variable, if the os doesn't do that automatically.

@cfr - I’m looking through the memoize-code.pdf file now to see what I can find, if anything. Compiling memoize.tex file on the command line presents in an error: Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14. Which -a python results in /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python, e.g. two identical lines.

sorry, where's memoize.tex from? and that does not look like a tex or latex error. what command did you use exactly?

My MWE memoize.tex (from Sec 2.1 in Memoize v1.4.1 December 2, 2024 package documentation). Re: that does not look like a tex or latex error - I know!! Strange...

This is odd… although the compiler definitely generates an Error: Python module 'pdfrw' was not found., if I hit enter, compiling resumes and the image on Pg. 9 (section 2.1) is generated. The memoize package is definitely finding the pdfrw module. So it appears there’s a ‘hickup' of sorts in the memoize package that trips the file not found error, but allows compilation to continue. Wondering if there is some way to skip over and ignore the file not found error during compilation until the memoize package author can have a look to see what is going on. (That’s enough for one day.)

that would be expected behaviour. if extraction succeeds, you should get a directory with externalised images (.pdf) alongside memos (.memo) and ccmemos (.ccmemo) with long file hashes as their names.

@cfr Thanks for the info. Is the Error: Python module 'pdfrw' was not found. expected behavior when using the memoize package? If so, when compiling, is there any way to avoid having to hit the enter key to continue compiling when the memoize package error appears?

no, that is not expected. it is expected that you'll still get images if you continue, but it is not expected that you get an error. I'm guessing nothing is getting extracted so the images are being recreated each time (even without recompile), but that's just a guess.

[Not an answer; too messy/long for a comment.]
Python extraction works for me with:
$ pip show pdfrw
Name: pdfrw
Version: 0.4
Summary: PDF file reader/writer library
Home-page: https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw
Author: Patrick Maupin
Author-email: pmaupin@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

According to the manual, either pdfrw or pdfrw2 should work (p 28). Sometimes GUI editors don't use the same environment as the CLI. To test if this might be the problem, try compiling on the command line, where you know python finds the library.
You need to load memoize before loading tikz or forest.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[extract=python]{memoize}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}

\begin{document}

Memoize will automatically externalize

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(node)
  [align=center,ellipse,draw]
  {TikZ\\pictures};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{forest}
  [and Forest trees [and]
    [Forest trees[Forest][trees]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

For comparison:
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python312.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.12', '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages']

